# binding relational data to crystal Report / xtraReport

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, sql-server-ce, xtrareport

I wanted to Show Well Designed and valuable Report for application user, Now I don't know how to Show Relational Data into Report ?
Explain:
I have Some Tables in Database : Party, Quality, Color And Bill.
In [Bill] Table Party, quality and color are refer as  partyID, qualityID, colorID. 
Now, Probleam is that, In Bill Table party, color, quality are stored as ID and I need their Name not ID in Report. In short, I want Party Name not PartyID, color Name Not colorID And quality not qualityID in My Report.
so, please guide me in right way

Comment: You need to JOIN your tables based on their IDs, check this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I have already done... but, i don,t have any idea that how to bind table adapter( myFillData method) with report...

Comment: You don't need a table adapter, just create a database connection inside the report document and add the SQL query inside a command. For more info check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHNHsIUbcn8

Comment: thanks for your answer but, I'm using sql compact edition 3.5 and it doesn't support SQL query...

Comment: This is very weird, but you're absolutely right. You can use a dataset as a datasource for your report. To retrieve a dataset from SQL Server CE, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 and to bind a dataset to the report this http://developer-content.emc.com/developer/downloads/CrystalReport_ADO_Dataset.pdf

Comment: ok. I got the solution. Just make New Table Adapter And Bind it With Report it's very simple... The Problem Occurs because of tfs, it's not updated in my Local Data so,There is no problem using with table adapter and thanks @David-